# django model and csv file zip feature lack

Tags: django, csv, zip

I fixed a lot with your help and I guess we come to last problem;
If the line from the csv file not in the my django model database than django mixes up all so that; csv line and django database are no longer going in correct order so all mixed.
To prevent this problem I added if queryset count function within the loop to raise an error message or tried also pushing another default value but nothing worked. What you would suggest to prevent this sync problem ?

```
                   for instance in RFP.objects.filter(FP_Item=query):
                        if RFP.objects.filter(FP_Item=query).count() >= 1:
                            instances.append(instance)
                        else:
                            messages.success(request, "ERROR")
```

For reference the whole code:

```
 with open(path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
            data = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
            for row in data:
                line = row[0]
                lines.append(line)
                query = line
                for instance in FP.objects.filter(FP_Item=query):
                    if FP.objects.filter(FP_Item=query).count() <= 1:
                        instances.append(instance)
                    else:
                        messages.success(request, "ERROR")
            pair = zip(lines, instances)
            context = {'pair': pair,
                       }
            return render(request, 'check_fp.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use filter queryset and for if else loops.
You need to use get function with try and except to catch empty instance.

```
                try:
                    instance = FP.objects.get(FP_Item=query)
                    instances.append(instance)
                except FP.DoesNotExist:
                    instance = ["Check"]
                    instances.append(instance)
            pair = zip(lines, instances)
```